# Переопределение методов класса QSlider

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, pyqt, qslider

Как реализовать поведение слайдера как у ползунка управления громкостью *Windows 10*?

Конкретно - я нажимаю на область громкости и ползунок сразу перескакивает на это место. Это я реализовал, ниже в примере.

---

Но как сделать так, чтобы после перескакивания ползунка, он оказывался в состоянии, когда левая кнопка мыши (ЛКМ) еще зажата, чтобы я сразу мог двигать его дальше по полю, **`без повторного зажатия ЛКМ`** ?

---

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Slider(QtWidgets.QSlider):
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super(Slider, self).mousePressEvent(event)
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            val = self.pixelPosToRangeValue(event.pos())
            self.setValue(val)

    def pixelPosToRangeValue(self, pos):
        opt = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionSlider()
        self.initStyleOption(opt)
        gr = self.style().subControlRect(QtWidgets.QStyle.CC_Slider, opt, QtWidgets.QStyle.SC_SliderGroove, self)
        sr = self.style().subControlRect(QtWidgets.QStyle.CC_Slider, opt, QtWidgets.QStyle.SC_SliderHandle, self)

        if self.orientation() == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
            sliderLength = sr.width()
            sliderMin = gr.x()
            sliderMax = gr.right() - sliderLength + 1
        else:
            sliderLength = sr.height()
            sliderMin = gr.y()
            sliderMax = gr.bottom() - sliderLength + 1;
        pr = pos - sr.center() + sr.topLeft()
        p = pr.x() if self.orientation() == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal else pr.y()
        return QtWidgets.QStyle.sliderValueFromPosition(self.minimum(), self.maximum(), p - sliderMin,
                                               sliderMax - sliderMin, opt.upsideDown)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    flay = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(w)
    w1 = QtWidgets.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
    w2 = Slider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
    flay.addRow("default: ", w1)
    flay.addRow("modified: ", w2)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам просто надо переместить `super(Slider, self).mousePressEvent(event)` в конец метода `def mousePressEvent(self, event):`

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Slider(QtWidgets.QSlider):

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
#        super(Slider, self).mousePressEvent(event)          #  ---

        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            val = self.pixelPosToRangeValue(event.pos())
            print(f"{val}")
            self.setValue(val)

        super(Slider, self).mousePressEvent(event)           # +++ <<<------------

    def pixelPosToRangeValue(self, pos):
        opt = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionSlider()
        self.initStyleOption(opt)
        gr = self.style().subControlRect(QtWidgets.QStyle.CC_Slider, opt, QtWidgets.QStyle.SC_SliderGroove, self)
        sr = self.style().subControlRect(QtWidgets.QStyle.CC_Slider, opt, QtWidgets.QStyle.SC_SliderHandle, self)

        if self.orientation() == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
            sliderLength = sr.width()
            sliderMin = gr.x()
            sliderMax = gr.right() - sliderLength + 1
        else:
            sliderLength = sr.height()
            sliderMin = gr.y()
            sliderMax = gr.bottom() - sliderLength + 1;
        pr = pos - sr.center() + sr.topLeft()
        p = pr.x() if self.orientation() == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal else pr.y()
        return QtWidgets.QStyle.sliderValueFromPosition(self.minimum(), self.maximum(), p - sliderMin,
                                               sliderMax - sliderMin, opt.upsideDown)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    flay = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(w)
    w1 = QtWidgets.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
    w2 = Slider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
    flay.addRow("default: ", w1)
    flay.addRow("modified: ", w2)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```